# When running php script which runs for 5 minutes I can not access this file in another browser tab

Tags: php, ubuntu, process, apache2

When running php script which runs for 5 minutes I can not access this file in another browser tab. It shows that this tab is loading, but it load only when first ends.

Is there problem in sessions or can you suggest something to solve this problem?

How can I solve this problem? I need sessions.

Comment: Are you using sessions? Sessions are blocking

Comment: Please provide your code so we have a chance to solve your problem. You really should not have a PHP-script the executes for 5 minutes. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `session_write_close()` as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, access to session state is synchronized. You have to close the session to allow another request to access it. You can use [session-write-close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) to close the session.

Most of the time, you don't need to change session state after initializing. So just copy session to a local variable:

```
// Copy session data to local variable
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION;
session_write_close();

// now use $session instead of $_SESSION
if (isset($session['foo'])) {
    echo $session['foo'];
}

// Optionally open the session again to write something
// may lead to synchronization issues with parallel requests
session_start();
if ($reckless) {
    $session['foo'] = 'bar';
    $_SESSION = $session;
} else {
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

Opening the session again to change it is a bad move in most circumstances. Ask yourself why you are using session state at all. Try to restructure your requests so they don't rely on it.